# How to set base url in Flying-Saucer, while rendering HTML to PDF?

Tags: java, xhtml, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I am trying to render a HTML page to PDF using Flying-Saucer. The HTML is created in memory and passed to the renderer as

```
renderer.setDocumentFromString(new String(htmlByteArray));
```

The issue is that I have `<img src="images.jpg"/>` in the HTML and it is not getting rendered in the final HTML. The image is located in the `resources` folder in the package.

I tried setting the base url with the following, but with no success:

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.getSharedContext().setBaseURL("com/org/tools/designer/resources/");
System.out.println(renderer.getSharedContext().getBaseURL());
renderer.setDocumentFromString(new String(htmlByteArray));
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
```

Comment: Have you tried `setBaseURL` with an actual base **URL**? E.g. `file:///---path-to-resources---com/org/tools/designer/resources/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theres a really cool interface in FS called `UserAgentCallback` that allows you to get all your own resources. For other people looking at this you can set your url accordingly:

```
renderer.getSharedContext().getUserAgentCallback().setBaseURL("url_to_resources");
```

However you have a special case here, you have resources embedded inside your jar file that need a special way to be accessed. You can implement your own `UserAgentCallback` Heres a little one I wrote up for you. (I did not test this so you may have to debug it a bit).

This code bit extends the `ITextUserAgent` that way you only have to overwrite the `getBinaryResource` method and leave the rest up to the library. If this isnt working out you can look into implementing a full on `UserAgentCallback`.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextOutputDevice;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextUserAgent;

public class PackageUserAgentCallback extends ITextUserAgent {
    private Class resourceClass;

    public PackageUserAgentCallback(ITextOutputDevice outputDevice, Class resourceClass) {
        super(outputDevice);
        this.resourceClass = resourceClass;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBinaryResource(String uri) {
        try {
            InputStream in = resourceClass.getResourceAsStream(uri);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int numRead;
            byte [] buffer = new byte[256];
            while((numRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
            }
            return out.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then you can set this to your `UserAgentCallback`, this would direct all resource requests through your `PackageUserAgentCallback`

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.getSharedContext().setUserAgentCallback(
        new PackageUserAgentCallback(renderer.getOutputDevice(), Resources.class));
System.out.println(renderer.getSharedContext().getBaseURL());
renderer.setDocumentFromString(new String(htmlByteArray));

renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
```